# How to add words on a picture and bold one of them using Pillow in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I add text on the image using PIL library in Python. How can I bold one word in a sentence? Let's say I want to write in the picture: "This is an **example** sentence".

Comment: “Not all questions benefit from including code.” — it’s from the article you’ve linked first.

Comment: I am aware of that, I was just suggesting it would have been better if you provided a template code to work with, though I understand that it wouldn't have been beneficial to the primary question, but would have benefited the person writing the answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't bold, underline, italicize etc. certain parts of a sentence. You can use multiple separate `.text()` commands and change their x-y coordinates to make it look like one sentence. To bold text, you can use a bolded text font in a font family, and use that font for a `.text()` command. In the example below, I used the Arial and the Arial Bold font. I am on a windows machine, so the file paths will be different on Linux or Mac.

Code:

```
#import statements
import PIL
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont

#save fonts
font_fname = '/fonts/Arial/arial.ttf'
font_fname_bold = '/fonts/Arial/arialbd.ttf'
font_size = 25

#regular font
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_fname, font_size)

#bolded font
font_bold = ImageFont.truetype(font_fname_bold, font_size)

#Open test image. Make sure it is in the same working directory!
with Image.open("test.jpg") as img:
    #Create object to draw on
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    
    #Add text
    draw.text(xy=(10,10),text="Gardens have ",font=font)
    draw.text(xy=(175,10),text="many",font=font_bold)
    draw.text(xy=(240,10),text=" plants and flowers",font=font)

#Display new image
img.show()
```

Test image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU75J.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will use this method for now. Hopefully in the future, the library's creators will make this process easier.